# Sql query to fetch the next token number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column TokenId list in my SQL table "Tokendata".

```
The TokenId has values say 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11
```

Here the above tokenIds are occupied. When I query this table, it should give me the next free tokenId, in this case it should be **5**.

If TokenId has values say **"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,13,20"**, the query should return me **9**.

Can anyone help me with a SQL query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. But it may not be the optimistic solution. Optimized solutions are welcome

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    TableID  int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TokenId int
)
Insert Into @TempTable 
    Select tt.TokenId from XLBDataPoint tt where tt.TokenId= 1
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TempTable ) 

(SELECT 
Top 1 t.TokenId + @RowCount 
FROM TokenData  t
Where t.TokenId+ @RowCount  NOT in
(select t2.TokenId FROM TokenData t2)
```

Comment: Maybe it's irrelevant, but I'm just curious: your question is tagged `mysql`, but the script in your answer is Transact-SQL. Why? What platform did you actually want a solution for?

Answer (score 3):

*Note: updated to account for cases where `1` is missing, as per the comment.*

```
SELECT
  t.TokenId + 1
FROM (
  SELECT TokenId
  FROM Tokendata
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0
) t
  LEFT JOIN Tokendata t2 ON t.TokenId = t2.TokenId - 1
WHERE t2.TokenId IS NULL
ORDER BY t.TokenId
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your query returns 9 for this data "2,3,4,5,6,7,8". But it should actually return 1

Comment: You never mentioned that `1` must always be the beginning. Anyway, I think my edit should take care of that.

Comment: @Rockstart: You mean it still returns `9` instead of `1`? It does work [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d086/2), by the way.

Comment: @Andiry: Yes it is still returning 9 when the record is {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Comment: @Rockstart: Did you try my query on SQL Fiddle by the link I gave you? Was my test set-up correct? Was it perhaps missing anything important that should have been taken into account? Maybe you could set up *your* test case on SQL Fiddle and demonstrate how my solution was returning an incorrect result? I don't mean to push you, just interested in finding out what is wrong with this query, that's all.